# Manipulating Large Amounts of Image Data in Python

Tags: python, image

I have a large number of images of different categories, e.g. "Cat", "Dog", "Bird". The images have some hierarchical structure, like a dict. So for example the key is the animal name and the value is a list of animal images, e.g. `animalPictures[animal][index]`.

I want to manipulate each image (e.g. compute histogram) and then save the manipulated data in an identical corresponding structure, e.g. `animalPictures['bird'][0]` has its histogram stored in `animalHistograms['bird'][0]`.

The only issue is I do not have enough memory to load all the images, perform all the manipulations, and create an additional structure of the transformed images.

Is it possible to load an image from disk, manipulate the image, and stream the data to a dict on disk? This way I could work on a per-image basis and not worry about loading everything into memory at once.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the[`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html#module-shelve)module which provides dictionary-like persistent objects backed by a file object. For the most part you can use them like ordinary dictionaries, so converting any existing code that uses them is relatively easy. There's couple of additional methods for controlling the writing back of any cached entries and closing the object.

Basically it will let you transparently store your Python dictionary data in an underlying file-based database. All entries accessed are also cached in memory.  However you can prevent the cache from consuming too much memory by manually calling the `sync()` method which writes any modified entries back to disk and empties the cache.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, if you us NumPy and especially `numpy.memmap` to store the image data. That way the image data looks as if it were in memory but is on the disk using the `mmap` mechanism. The nice thing is that the `numpy.memmap` arrays are not more difficult to handle than ordinary arrays.

There is some performance overhead as all `memmap` arrays are saved to disk. The arrays could be described as "disk-backed arrays", i.e. the data is also kept in RAM as long as possible. This means that if you access some data array very often, it is most likely in memory, and there is no disk read overhead.

So, keep your metadata in a dict in memory, but `memmap` your bigger arrays.

This is probably the easiest way. However, make sure you have a 64-bit Python in use, as the 32-bit one runs out of addresses ad 2 GiB.

Of course, there are a lot of ways to compress the image data. If your data may be compressed, then you might consider using compression to save memory.

Comment: Is there some basic code in python where I can process a large raster (20G+) in chunks/patches (I believe it's called sliding window) using numpy's memmap? Thanks in advance.